# Runtime error when NSString Object is released

Tags: cocoa

In my Function below if I remove the tempString release statement it works just fine but with it, there is ALWAYS a runtime error. It is a simple function that displays an array in an NSTextField either _stackDisp1 or _stackDisp2 but for some reason releasing the string creates a runtime error Any help?

```
- (void) displayArr:(NSMutableArray*)stack{
  NSTextField *myObj;
  if([stack count] <= 10) myObj = _stackDisp1;
  else myObj = _stackDisp2;
  NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@""];
  for(NSString *i in stack){
    tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",tempString,i];
  }
  [myObj setStringValue:tempString];
  [tempString release];
}
```

Comment: I thought if an object was created using alloc, the programmer was responsible for releasing it. Why is it being auto-released?

Comment: Then initial `tempString` was indeed created using `alloc` and would have to be released. But as you're never touching it anyway, by replacing it with autoreleased (`stringWithFormat:`) instances in your for loop, it's not needed in the first place. Replace the line with `initWithString:` with `NSString *tempString = @"";` and remove the `[tempString release];` or (and this is what you should do, instead of reinventing the wheel) use the code that I posted in my answer. There already is a method for what you're trying to do, so use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because

```
tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",tempString,i];
```

creates a new autoreleased object assigning it to your variable `tempString`. The pointer to the first object gets lost and you end up over-releasing an autoreleased object. Just change the initial assignment to

```
  NSString *tempString = @"";
```

and remove the `[tempString release]` line.

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop you're assigning `tempString` to an autoreleased string:

```
tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",tempString,i];
```

releasing it manually results in a BAD_ACCESS.

Also you are probably looking for this:

```
- (void) displayArr:(NSMutableArray*)stack{
  NSTextField *myObj = ([stack count] <= 10) ? _stackDisp1 : _stackDisp2;
  [myObj setStringValue:[stack componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"]];
}
```

<sup>The declaration/assignment of `myObj` was a bit too verbose for my taste,

so I used a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) instead (it's use is not essiential though. Just a matter of style.).</sup>